# Backbone.js error on script include

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

in chrome when looking at the resource tab in the inspector, I get the following error: uncaught TypeError: cannot call method 'extend' of undefined
Really looking to get into mvc development. Hope someone can point me towards the right direction.

Comment: can you post how you've included your `<script>` tags?

Comment: [Backbone isn't an MVC framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583742/backbone-js-vs-batman-js):).  But are you loading underscore BEFORE loading Backbone?  You have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extend` method comes from the [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library which is a requirement for Backbone. You need to include it before Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using any kind of framework - like Rails, CodeIgniter, Asp.net mvc, etc - but on your main Index page you can put this:

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>My Main Page</h1>

  <p>Here is some content</p>

    <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/backbone-localstorage.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom-backbone-code.js"></script>
</div>
```

Make sure that you have all these files downloaded and available for your project.  You should be able to get them - or at least links to them - from Backbone's website.

By loading the files at the bottom you are also making sure that dom elements load before the javascript files.  **The order of the Javascript files is very important.**

Here I have all the js files stored in a folder called "javascripts".  Be sure to change the names of Jquery to whatever versions that you have.  Also, if you aren't planning to use local storage, than you can just delete that line.

The 'custom-backbone-code.js' line is just a file to get you started writing your Backbone Views, Models, and Collections.